# React antd style radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I need to re-style the antd radio button.

I already did the following:

```
.ant-radio-button-wrapper {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.ant-radio-button-wrapper:hover {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.ant-radio-button-wrapper:focus-within {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but some things doesn't work yet...

- when I click somwhere outside of a radio button the background color of the selected radio button becomes white.
- when I select a radio button the radio button which was selected before blinks white.
- the border of the selected radio button doesn't work, it's still the blue default.

how can I fix this?

Comment: There's probably more css selectors that you need to override, maybe `active`

Comment: which? I've tried checked, selection, after, active, focuse
which should I try?